# How to fill an echoed <select> with PHP, after clicking a button

Tags: php, html

I have this problem, I'm using PHP to create an HTML document, creating everything with echo, my problem is that I'm creating a **select**, but it must be filled when the index of the other one changes, filling in doc creation is easy, but how can I fill it using PHP when selecting something in the other select?

```
$html_ciudad = '';
$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. "newContact.php";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
$div = $dom->getElementById("City");

foreach($ciudades->getCiudad($id) as $ciu){
    $newDiv = $dom->createElement('option');
    $newDiv->setIdAttribute($ciu["IdCd"]);
    $newDiv->nodeValue(utf8_encode($ciu["Cd"]));
    $div->appendChild($newDiv);
    $html_ciudad .=
        '<option id="'.$ciu["IdCd"].'" value="">'.utf8_encode($ciu["Cd"]).'</option>';
}
```

I tried that way, everything working, but not showing result, If someone knows how to do this, even if the code is completely different, is welcome haha thanks.

Comment: you're trying to do a cascading select? that's normally accomplished with JS+ajax, because otherwise you have to do a full-blown server roundtrip with full page rebuild to allow PHP to insert anything. And note that you're **NOT** loading html. you're loading a PHP script, and the php code tags **WILL** be treated as bad/corrupt html tags by the DOM parser.

Comment: That's with JS+ajax, right! I knew it :/ But my team leader insisted to try it with PHP, thank u, I will use JS

Comment: nothing wrong with doing it via php-only, but it's painful for the user because the whole page has to be reloaded every time they change a select in the "primary" dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understood it well, if your select value change, you should load from another page with ajax another select...This code may help:
in your main page:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   if(this.value==1){

        $("#div1").load("another_select.php");
   } 

})

</script>
```

in another_select.php page:

```
echo "<select>";
...
echo "</select>";
```